# What are the known ambiguous SMD IC package names?

Tags: surface-mount, packages, naming-conventions

I just recently discovered (the hard way...) that VSSOP-8 is an ambiguous IC package name. Some manufacturers use this name to describe a 0.65mm pitch device, whereas others use VSSOP-8 to describe a narrower 0.5mm pitch device. TI may even use both package sizes under the same name, requiring the user to double check which they mean in a device's datasheet.

As a result of this, I am in the process of auditing my PCB footprint libraries for IC footprints.

What are some other known ambiguous IC package names? I know that some SOIC-8 parts are wide whereas others are narrow, but are there others? Are any of the SMD IC package names unambiguous? Is there a longer, more official way to name these device packages to eliminate ambiguity (e.g., VSSOP-8,p0.5 for a 0.5mm pitch VSSOP-8)? Is there a standards organization like JEDEC that "governs" these package names?

Comment: They're all ambiguous since some manufacturers have their own designation for every package. TI being one of them. Analog Devices being another. The two VSSOP packages you are talking about have a unique designation code by TI and that's what you need to use.

Comment: What defines a part number from being ambiguous or unambiguous?

Comment: @VoltageSpike If a given package (not part) name has multiple interpretations (such as my example of VSSOP), then it is ambiguous. If there is only one interpretation of the package, then it isn't ambiguous. What I am looking for are names to use in my footprint library that aren't going to be subject to interpretation...

Answer (score 1):

> What are some other known ambiguous IC package names?

Most of the short names are.

> Are any of the SMD IC package names unambiguous? Is there a longer, more official way to name these device packages to eliminate ambiguity (e.g., VSSOP-8,p0.5 for a 0.5mm pitch VSSOP-8)? Is there a standards organization like JEDEC that "governs" these package names?

Yes, look up IPC-7351B. Below is an excerpt from the standard.

[image]

[Image source](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/jbj-generating-pcb-footprints-for-your-first-layout)